# Embed app outside Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

There are some apps in the store (Oberlo, Conversio, Shippo, etc) that are different from other apps, in that they open on a different tab when opened from the store's admin/apps. What are such applications called?  When should one follow such behavior for our apps?  Would Shopify deprecate this behavior?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

In-Shopify apps should respect shopify style, and use Polaris (a React component library).

So host an app outside Shopify can discharge developers from design, front-side and server-side restriction.

Here is a sample of in-shopify app using Polaris (and node.js) : https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-app

As far as I know, Shopify doesn't plan to deprecate this behavior

Comment: Is there any way to convert Shopify Embedded App into a non-embedded App? I am using shopify_app gem.

Answer (score 1):

Asked their support about having non-embedded Shopify apps, there's no restriction to make one. But they'd be deprecating apps using using both of the behaviours(embedded and non-embedded).

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the configuration, in your shopify_app configuration **embedded_app to false**. This will ultimately just change how your app authenticates and it will no longer rely on AppBridge on your front-end.

Comment: How then the app should authenticate when the merchant visits the app some days after installation? The merchant should always go to shopify admin/apps and click our app to open in new tab to our own domain? Or does merchant can open directly our app domain and we should support our own login?